# Is there any way to download aar from maven dependencies at jitpack

Tags: java, maven, jitpack

Is there any way to get only aar file from dependency name online?
I want to download aar file of this :  https://jitpack.io/#sshadkany/Android_neumorphic

Comment: please see the solution and let me know if you are able to download aar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the aar file of latest version 1.2.0 at the below location name of aar `android_neumorphic-release.aar`

https://github.com/sshadkany/Android_neumorphic/releases/tag/1.2.0